# Events Fired When DataGridView.SelectAll Called

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

What events are fired when `.SelectAll()` is called on a `DataGridView`? I want to intercept some cell selection without having to inherit another `DataGridView` and override the `SelectAll()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that SelectionChanged is fired after much troubleshooting. It would help if the MSDN documentation told you that when it details the SelectAll method.

Comment: I remember in VC++6 there was a way that you could capture all events as a program was running.  Did you use a similar tool?

Comment: Nope.. just traversed the list of events the hard way and put a messagebox until I got a hit. There has to be a better way